# Swipe button in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to make a swipe button. I want you to change the image of the button as I move to the right. And when I slide to the left, I want button image revert back.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var swipeButton: UIButton!
let swipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let swipeButtonRight: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("ButtonRight"))
        swipeButtonRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        self.swipeButton.addGestureRecognizer(swipeButtonRight)

    let swipeButtonLeft: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("ButtonLeft"))
        swipeButtonLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
        self.swipeButton.addGestureRecognizer(swipeButtonLeft)
}

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
{

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer
    {
        switch swipeGesture.direction
        {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right:
         swipeButton.setImage = UIImage(named:"x.png")

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
        swipeButton.setImage = UIImage(named:"y.png")

        default:
           break
        }
    }
}
}
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Your description on functionality sounds like you *really* should look at a UIScrollView instead of swiping. Put the two images in it, add code to make it "adjust" to show the image the user swipes to, and be done with it!

Comment: for `UIButton`s image you should be using `swipeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "x"), forState: .normal)` -- you are missing the `forState:`

Answer (score 1):

In the `action` parameter in the constructor of your gesture recogniser you tell the app to look for a method called "ButtonRight" (and "ButtonLeft"). You should pass in the actual method you want to be executed here (e.g. "respondToSwipeGesture").

Put a breakpoint inside "respondToSwipeGesture", and you'll see it never gets called.

Comment: How can i fix it? @ØyvindHauge

Comment: The syntax has been changing a lot in Swift, but I believe this should work: `#selector(respondToSwipeGesture:)`

Answer (score 1):

First judgment is not your switch does not correct judge the object

#selector(respondToSwipeGesture:)

Another way to set the picture should be written like this

SwipeButton.setImage (UIImage (named: "x"), forState: .normal)